# WAMP icon not reappearing after Windows 11 reboot

Tags: mariadb, icons, wamp

This morning I (a web newbie) smoothly downloaded and installed wamp64. Projects definition and an "echo 'Hello';" via index.php worked perfectly. However, adding a user and database with phpMyAdmin yielded only an error message. But I had previously installed a standalone php, with an editing of Windows' PATH. Since Googling suggested that might be the problem, I deleted my PATH edit and repeatedly restarted Windows 11. The WAMP64 icon has never reappeared, which makes wamp useless, at least for me.  (Of course on one restart I ineffectively tried restoring my PATH editing..)

None of the wamp64\logs*.log files show any abnormality. Task Manager reports that Apache and mysqld are indeed running. phpsysinfo seems happy, correctly reporting my last restart time.

However, mariadb seems not to be. (This Mariadb is inherited from an earlier [useless for me] WebDeveloper download and installation, which wamp64 has taken command of -- e.g., all the mariadb files are now in wamp64 directories).  The mariadb.log also lacks any entry from my last Windows 11 restarts. I thought of uninstalling mariadb, but it is not listed on Windows System's "/add/remove programs".

Here are some configuration details: Apache 2.4.58; php 8.2.13; mysql 8,2,0; MariaDB 11.2.2.

Comment: Problem seemingly solved, by finding and running "wamp64\restart_wampserver.bat"